# VBA error handling query

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel

I was hoping someone could have a look and tidy this up for me; I have to say error handling is not strong point of mine. I have the code block below and I have been playing around with some error handles but it is not as I really want it.

What I am trying to do is ensure that if at any point there is an error the workbook and excel instance I have opened are closed down gracefully.

I am sure there are much nicer and simpler ways to achieve this than what I have come up with.

```
Sub QOScode()

On Error GoTo Fail

Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
Dim book As Excel.Workbook
Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\QOS DGL stuff.xlsx")
'set up error handeling so if any thing happens the instance of excel with QOS sheets is closed gracefully

On Error GoTo Closebook
' MsgBox book.Sheets("ACLS").Cells(3, 3)
'Do what you have to do
' 

Closebook:
On Error Resume Next
book.Close SaveChanges:=False
app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
Fail:
End Sub
```

What I want is a single On error - close app and exit sub.

Can anyone provide a sample of what would be considered best practice for doing this?

Cheers

Aaron

So this code below, when the sheet does not exist it will cause the error, why does it not skip the "`book.close`" statement, I know this throws an error, but I want it to ignore it?

```
Sub QOScode()

On Error GoTo Closebook

Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False
Dim book As Excel.Workbook
Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\QOaS DGL stuff.xlsx") 'this sheet does not exist
'
MsgBox book.Sheets("ACLS").Cells(3, 3)
'Do what you have to do
'

Closebook:
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
book.Close SaveChanges:=False  'Object variable or with block variable not set (error 91)
app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with your current code? What is it that you want that does not happen?

Comment: Well nothing :) Unless of course for some reason an error prematurely closed the workbook and then "on error GOTO Closebook" was called. Even with the "GOTO next" statement, it still exits on the book.close SaveChanges:=False, with an error the object dose not exist. Is there a way to check that "book" exists, so I could do "If book exists then book.close"

Comment: But `On Error Goto Next` will make it go to the next statement which is `app.Quit` at which point everything is as you want it to be...

Comment: Sorry I meant to type "on error resume Next" In my current code, if for any reason the app or workbook get closed unexpectlay (there is no instance of them). the code errors out at the line "book.close" I expected that with the "resume next" it would just skip the line. I think may be the err.clear might be what i need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My 2 cents on Error Handling.

You **should** always do error handling.

***Some of the Reasons***

**1)** You wouldn't want your app to break down and leave your users hanging! Imagine the frustration that it would cause them.

**2)** Error handling doesn't mean that you are trying to ignore error.

**3)** Error handling is neither defensive programming or aggressive programming. IMHO it is proactive programming.

**4)** Very few people are aware that you can find out the line which is causing the error. The property that I am talking about is ERL. Consider this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long, k As Long

10  On Error GoTo Whoa

20  i = 5
30  j = "Sid"
40  k = i * j

50  MsgBox k

60  Exit Sub
Whoa:
70  MsgBox "Description  : " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
    "Error Number : " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
    "Error at Line: " & Erl
End Sub
```

[image]

**5)** In subs like worksheet change event, it is a must to do error handling. Imagine you have set the Enable Event to False and your code breaks! The code won't run next time till you set the events back to true

**6)** I can go on and on :-) Would recommend this link

**Topic: To ‘Err’ is Human**

**Link**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/

**Tip:**

Use [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx). It is free!

Here is how I would write your code.

```
Sub QOScode()
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook

10  On Error GoTo Whoa

20  Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\QOS DGL stuff.xlsx")

30  MsgBox book.Sheets("ACLS").Cells(3, 3)

    '
    'Do what you have to do
    '
LetsContinue:
40  On Error Resume Next
50  book.Close SaveChanges:=False
60  Set book = Nothing
70  app.Quit
80  Set app = Nothing
90  On Error GoTo 0
100 Exit Sub
Whoa:
110 MsgBox "Description  : " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
           "Error Number : " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
           "Error at Line: " & Erl
120 Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. MZ Tools is very useful when writing major code, especially for public release.

Comment: Yeah. One of the useful feature of MZ Tools which I frequently use is numbering my code lines. :)

Comment: +1 "Very few people are aware of Erl" Yeah, that could have something to do with it being completely undocumented as far as I can tell. Microsoft did a good job of hiding that one.

Comment: HI, I agree with what you say And your Whoa: block is the kind of think I would use (defiantly in production code). my issue is though that even in your code. Say line "30" causes the workbook to crash out and throws an error which calls "Whoa:". The code will still then error out at line "book.close" and the script will halt rather then resume the next line "app.quit"

Comment: @DevilWAH: No it will not halt :) Did you try the above code? I just tested it by creating a new workbook called QOS DGL stuff.xlsx. And the error happened at line 30 as there was no sheet called "ACLS". It gave the error message and exited gracefully :)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Yes, unfortunately it's not documented as it should have been. I learnt about it many years ago from MZ Tools.

Comment: see my second bit of code nn my original quesion. where the namei have for the workbook to open is wrong or does not exist. on my system that code crashes out. hcih shold be same as your code but with out the message block

Comment: @DevilWAH: Even when I changed the file name to a non existent file name, the code still doesn't halt :) Regarding MZTools, it will run on Office 32 bit installed on a 64 bit but yes it will not run on Office 64 bit :(

Comment: Yep indeed, sadly our computers have to have the company standard applications that included 64bit office. And I cant develop on a non company computers as lot of the resources needed with in scripts can only be accessed but company computers :(. But what is the difference between my code and you code that is causing what I am seeing?

Comment: I want to emphasize/expand point 5, if you disable Events, ScreenUpdating or Calculation you need to use error handling, period.  Even the best programmers make mistakes.

Comment: @Reafidy I think we are all in agreement when and where error handling should be used. My question sill remains of why the error handling (which is a work in progress) in my code block dose not do what I expect? Ie. an error after the statement "on error resume next" still causes the script to halt with an error message.

Comment: @DevilWAH: I have tested the code and it doesn't halt. Can you show the exact code that you are using?

Comment: The exact code in my original question. (second example) the comment shows what error message i get. Just opened a brand new workbook, created new module and pasted the code in to it. Ran it and got "Object variable or with block variable not set (error code given is 91)"

Comment: @DevilWAH: Not for any points but could you please try my code?

Comment: Ok interesting, "10 Closebook:
20 Resume Next
30 On Error Resume Next" Works which is what your code is doing with "resume LetsContinue". But on my system with out the "20 resume next" it crashes out. Looking closer and stepping through the code, adding "resume next" makes the code run the "msgbox ....." line, and this seems to fix the problem? If i change line 10 in your code to say "on error GOTO LetContinue" the code give the same error I am seeing.

Comment: @DevilWAH: I am sorry, I don't understand what you just said. :) If you write the code as I have written you will not get the error :)

Comment: That's correct, but if I change Line 10 of you code to say "on error GOTO LetsContinue", I do get the error. why should missing out the block of message code do this. So in summary, you current code works. changing only line 10 to jump straight to "LetsContinue" on an error and it halts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7627/discussion-between-devilwah-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Cheers for helping me with this, and working out the root issue I was seeing. So now I know you can't uses error checking with in the error section, after "on error goto xxx" it needs to be followed by a "resume statement". Star :)

Comment: @DevilWAH: Like I mentioned, I didn't do it for points. You didn't have to unselect the previous answer. I continued the discussion as I was simply curious as to why your code was not working as expected.

Comment: I know but honestly, I think any one reading this question can clearly see that your answer contains a lot of information and answers regarding my question. Its a pity there is not a system such as on Expert exchange where things can be split. I think with all the pointers you have given you have given the most complete answer.

Comment: @devilwah i'm ok with the unaccept. While I do think splitting the error handling into forseeable/catchall buckets (as my code does) is preferable, Sid did give you a good response on your while your error handling wasn't working as you exepected

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure I understand your objective.  If I did, I would probably disagree.

Is this code you are developing?  I almost never use error handling in code I am developing.  I want the interpreter to stop on the statement that gives the error.  I want to understand why that error has occurred.  What could I have done to avoid the error?  Did I fail to check the file exists?  Did I fail to check the path is accessable?  I will add the missing code before I do anything else.

By the time you have finished development, you should plan for there to be no error condition for which you have not included proper code.  Of course, this is impossible; you cannot make your code foolproof because fools are so ingenious.  The version you release to users must contains error handling.

But you could not release this code to users since it would stop without warning.  Would the user guess something had gone wrong with the macro or would they assume this was what was supposed to happen?  If they decide the macro has failed what are they going to say to you?  "It did not do what I was expecting and I do not know why."  What are you going to say back?  "What were you doing?"  I do not think I have ever had a user give a believable description of what they were doing at the time of a failure.  At the very least you want:

```
Call MsgBox("Sorry I have had an unrecoverable error within QOScode()." & _
            " Please record: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & _
            " and report to extension 1234")
```

With this, the user does not wonder if something has gone wrong and you know where it went wrong and, with luck, why.

Comment: I am calling a second app that is hidden, so while developing (an indeed in the final code)if any thing happens I want a routine that will gracefully close this down, Other wise every time I am running a debug and some thing unexpected happens, the code quits and I am left with the hidden app still running. So like you say, its important to cover all possibilities, having code that will gracefully shut down the app, means what ever other error code I have for the rest of the sub, I can be sure that this always get called, After error messages have been displayed, or logs written.

Answer (score 5):

To handle the foreseen issue neatly you can use short error handling to test that the Workbook actually exists  (ie `If Not Wb Is Nothing Then`, if so work on it, with a common ending (ie destroying the object)

The second sample shows how to add additional handling for unforeseen errors once the workbook has been opened.I have used `Err.Raise` to create deliberate error to give the user a choice as to how to proceed (close the workbook immediately post error *or* make the workbook visible)

As an aside, don't use `Dim` and `New` together. I have re-written
`Dim app As New Excel.Application`
into
`Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

 Set xlApp = New Excel.Application`

**1. Handling the no workbook issue**

```
Sub QOScode()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\QOaS DGL stuff.xlsx")    'this sheet does not exist
    On Error GoTo 0    '

    If Not Wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Wb.Sheets("ACLS").Cells(3, 3)
        'Do what you have to do
        Wb.Close False
    End If

    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**2. Handling no workbook and other unforseen error which may otherwise leave the worbook open**

```
Sub QOScode2()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim lngChk As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\QOaS DGL stuff.xlsx")    'this sheet does not exist
    On Error GoTo 0    '

    If Not Wb Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo ProblemHandler
        MsgBox Wb.Sheets("ACLS").Cells(3, 3)
        'Do what you have to do

        'Deliberate error
        Err.Raise 2000, "test code", "Sample Error"
        Wb.Close False
    Else
        MsgBox "Workbook not found,code will now exit"
    End If

    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ProblemHandler:
    'Test to see if workbook was still open when error happened
    If Not Wb Is Nothing Then
        lngChk = MsgBox("The code encountered an error" & vbNewLine & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Do you want to close the file?", vbYesNo, Err.Description)
        If lngChk = vbYes Then
            'close book. Code will proceed to destroy app
            Wb.Close False
        Else
            'make workbook visible and leave code
            Wb.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The code encountered an error - the file was already closed at this point" & vbNewLine & "Error number " & Err.Number & vbNewLine, Err.Description
    End If
    'destroy app (either if the workbook was closed, or user chose to close it)
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This would solve the issue I am having, but does any one know why the code I have errors out even with the "resume next statement? why does it not just ignore the "book.close False" line in my original code?

Comment: Cheers for the tips, I like the idea of checking if work book exists and then acting on it, this it what I was looking for as I think its much nice to handle foreseen errors with logic and leave error handling to the unforeseen stuff.